# MSBuild Managed vs Unmanaged property

Tags: msbuild, unmanaged, managed

Is there a way in MSBuild logic to determine if I am running managed vs unmanaged code?  Not C++ vs C#, but just managed vs unmanaged?  I'd like to set some properties (usually just version information) differently depending on whether the code is managed or unmanaged.

Comment: *running managed vs unmanaged code* do you mean *building* (as in *compiling/linking*) or effectively *running* an application? In the first case: what project type are you using? It's not as simple as *Not C++ vs C#*: in a C# project it's managed, in a C++ it can be both

Comment: "in a C++ it can be both" Do you mean both or either?  I am using this same logic across many projects, some are c# (always managed), and some are C++ (sometimes compiling managed sometimes not).  So I mean compiling managed (using the clr) vs compiling unmanaged.

Comment: Sorry meant 'either' indeed. But now I understand what you're after.

Answer (score 4):

There are normally two things that change in a vcxproj file for managed complation (afaik, at least that's how we have it in our master c++/cli property sheet used for all cli projects: the `CLRSupport` property is set to true and the `ClCompile` ItemGroup has the `CompileAsManaged` metadata set to true. You can check on any of these or both. Here's a target which prints the values:

```
<Target Name="CheckManaged">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="dummy.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CompileAsManaged>@(ClCompile->AnyHaveMetadataValue('CompileAsManaged','true'))</CompileAsManaged>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Message Text="CompileAsManaged is $(CompileAsManaged) and CLRSupport is $(CLRSupport)" />

  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Remove="dummy.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

As you can see getting the `CompileAsManaged` metadata value requires some treatment: I'm adding an item to the ClCompile group because if the group is empty you canot use CompileAsManaged; normally you can just omit this.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, each item in ClCompile (list of source files) has a `CompileAsManaged` metadata value.  Setting properties is difficult since it can vary for each source file, but is more straightforward if you only expect (and support) keying off the whole-project setting.  Toggle that in the IDE and see what changes in the vcxproj file.  It has a few different values to choose from.